# Prove that $\langle S_z\rangle=S\cos\theta$ for spin coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states

I'm trying to prove that $\langle {S_{z}} \rangle =S \cos \theta$ using the
notion of spin coherent states, so $|\theta,\phi \rangle  =  e ^{ -i \phi S_{z} } e ^{ -i \theta S_{y} } |S \rangle$, and i know that $\langle S|S_{y}|S \rangle$ =  $\langle S|S_{x}|S \rangle $= 0  and $\langle S|S_{z}|S \rangle=0$.

But I'm stuck in the very beginning

$\langle \theta,\phi|  e ^{ i \phi S_{y} } e ^{ i \theta S_{z} }  \theta S_{z} 
e ^{ -i \phi S_{z} } e ^{ -i \theta S_{y} } | \theta,\phi \rangle = \langle S|  e ^{ i \phi S_{y} } e ^{ i \theta S_{z} }  \theta S_{z} 
e ^{ -i \phi S_{z} } e ^{ -i \theta S_{y} } |S \rangle$

I have the BCH formula $ e ^{ -X } Ye ^{ X } = Y + [X,Y].... $ but i don't see how to use it with this $i \theta $

Answer (score 2):

1. You forgot to interchange the order of rotations in your bra vector, i.e. if 
   $\vert\theta,\phi\rangle=R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)\vert SS\rangle$ then 
   $\langle \theta,\phi\vert=\langle SS\vert R_y^{-1}(\theta) R_z^{-1}(\phi)$.
2. You have a typo and there is no $\theta S_z$, just $S_z$, i.e you need to compute
   $$
   \langle SS\vert R_y^{-1}(\theta)R_z^{-1}(\phi)S_zR_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)\vert SS\rangle.
   $$